# Get values for each row in a csv from the values of a dictionary composed of numpy arrays, if key matches with row string

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray, word2vec

I have a dictionary composed of numpy arrays which are the vectors generated from the output of my word2vec model. The size of the dict is around 2000. Providing a sample of the data here:

```
my_dict = {'disease a': array([ 0.2520773 ,  0.433798],
      dtype=float32), 'disease b': array([0.12321666, 0.64195603],
      dtype=float32), 'disease c': array([0.38915345, 0.5541569], dtype=float32)}
```

I have a column in a csv which is in this form:

```
disease a, disease c
disease b
disease c, disease b
disease c
```

For each row in the csv I want to check if each element in a row is present in the dictionary key and if present I want to get the values for that dictionary key in the csv.

So, output should look like:

```
Disease                             Vectors
disease a, disease c         [[ 0.2520773 ,  0.433798],[0.38915345, 0.5541569]]
disease b                    [0.12321666, 0.64195603]
disease c, disease b         [[0.38915345, 0.5541569],[0.12321666, 0.64195603]]
disease c                    [0.38915345, 0.5541569]
```

Code till now:

```
rows=[]
with open("Documents/vectors.csv", 'r') as csvfile:  
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    fields = next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader: 
        rows.append(row)            
for i in rows:
    for j in my_dict.keys():
        match = [i.split(",") for i in i]
        print(match)
        if match ==j:
            assign = my_dict.get(j)
            print(assign)
```

This is not working and I am not getting the value of the matched keys. Can anyone please help me to solve this

Comment: What is the line about `fields` there in your code for? (Nothing then happens to `fields`.) What do you think a `row` will be? Why is there an `for i in i`? (You'll always want the variable which you're taking one of at a time to be different variable name, for clarity, from the variable being iterated over.) Splitting `'disease a, disease b'` on `','` will make the 2nd item `' disease b'` (note the extra leading space), which may not work. And, you don't need to iterate over all your dict's keys to look up one key! The point a dict is to offer direct `my_dict.get(any_key)` access.

Comment: But really, why do you want to print that precise format you've shown in the example output? (It looks quite non-useful for any real purpose, or even human-review of a report.)